# XSD string restriction to charset

Tags: xml, soap, xsd

We define a SOAP interface to our application. Almost any string value can be any Unicode character, except for some legacy field values, where only subset of Latin-1 charset is accepted.

Is it possible to define a restriction on string value in XSD schema to contain only characters from Latin-1 charset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure

```
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
  <xs:pattern value="(\p{IsBasicLatin}|\p{isLatin-1Supplement})*"/>
</xs:restriction>
```

Alternatively (for characters allowed in XML 1.0)

```
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
  <xs:pattern value="[\t\r\n&#x20;-&#xff;]*"/>
</xs:restriction>
```

Comment: I was reading [http://www.w3.org/TR/xsd-unicode-blocknames/](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsd-unicode-blocknames/) and I saw you have contributed to writting it, so I was hoping I could test and post an answer before you post an answer ;) Anyway, _BasicLatin_ and _Latin1Supplement_ sum 256 characters total (first 256 unicode characters), so I think `&#x20;` should be `&#x00;`

Comment: But `&#x00;` is not a legal XML character reference: you can only refer to characters that are legal in XML (and this varies between XML 1.0 and XML 1.1).